# MySQL : How to make between as fast as equal?

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement where I want to fetch records from a table for next 7 days which can be easily done as below (this is just a sample query)

```
SELECT billnumber FROM bill WHERE paiddate BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

But this take a lot of time to execute(103 sec) while if i try with equal operator for each individual date, the execution type reduces less than half a sec for each date (0.297 sec). Sample query:

```
SELECT billnumber FROM bill WHERE paiddate = DATE(NOW())
```

and similarly for all the next 6 days. In this way, I would have to execute query 7 times for next day every time. Is there a way i could make 'between' to work as fast as equals (the combined execution time for all 7 individual date query doesn't take more than 2 sec)? Or is there any faster way to fetch next 7 days data?

Comment: Is there a typo in the second query, did you mean DATE(NOW())?
With the way it is written, paiddate = NOW() - it is very unlikely to return anything.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, corrected it.

Comment: There is no obvious, logical explantation based on the information given.  You have stated that this is a "sample" query, and I would be inclined to counter that perhaps it is not a valid, representive sample.  Are you familiar with using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see the optimizer's query plan?  The explanation for performance issues is almost always found there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `UNION` for unique billnumber or `UNION ALL` which does not consider uniqueness.

```
SELECT billnumber FROM bill WHERE paiddate = NOW()
UNION ALL
SELECT billnumber FROM bill WHERE paiddate = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT billnumber FROM bill WHERE paiddate = NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT billnumber FROM bill WHERE paiddate = NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT billnumber FROM bill WHERE paiddate = NOW() + INTERVAL 4 DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT billnumber FROM bill WHERE paiddate = NOW() + INTERVAL 5 DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT billnumber FROM bill WHERE paiddate = NOW() + INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was actually a sample query, and the actual query is some 27 lines long and making it union would make it very much unreadable but yes your solution do provide a way to do it. If I wouldn't find any other way, would consider this. Thanks for your response.

Comment: you are welcome. And hope you will get a better answer :)